# How can I restrict view pemissions to a node related child nodes?

Tags: 7, users

Let's say I have a parent node with ID equal to 233 that has the following related nodes: 234, 235, 236 (in a relationship field).
Is it possible to restrict access to paths node/234, and node/235, if they are a specific content type, but still show them for the same users in a embedded view inside a local task of ID equal to 233?

Comment: Hello, cmos; welcome on _Drupal Answers_. By embedded view do you mean a view created with Views?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/324/how-do-i-hide-drupal-nodes-that-shouldnt-be-directly-accessed-from-users-and-sea.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: yes I am embedding related nodes in the node template by adding something like this: <?php $view = views_get_view('products_features');
     print $view->preview('attachment_1', $node->nid); ?>

Comment: @Bedir : the problem with hook_node_access() is that it removes the possibility of viewing the nodes in the embedded view. Because I can only check for the following operations: 'create','delete', 'update', 'view'. But when I am embedding the view I am actually in the 'view' operation and the nodes I am blocking for 'view' will be blocked in the embedded view aswell.

Comment: @cmos: You could for example check the path in your hook_node_access() implementation, and deny access if viewed directly on node/x or only allow when viewed through a specific path. Also, please accept your own answer, so that this question is correctly marked as resolved.

Comment: @Berdir not able to mark it for another 2 hours ( because is my own question)

Comment: @cmos: Ok, didn't know what there was a restriction. I'm just trying to educate people that upvoting and accepting answers is important (to get it out of beta at some point, but also to encourage people to come back and give good answers). Didn't want to bother you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the comments I realized that in my case at least the best way of limiting the access  for unauthorized users (anonymous mainly) is **to not publish the child nodes**. And I removed the 'published'='yes' filter in the view itself so I can show those nodes in the parent template. And it works nicely. Thank you for the tips.