# How to block / restrict a list of URLs using Rules?

Tags: rules, redirection

I'm currently blocking access to some admin menu pages using the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module as follows:

**Events**: Drupal is initializing

**Conditions**:

- Data comparison > Data to compare:[site:current-page:url] then URL1 to block
- Data comparison > Data to compare:[site:current-page:url] then URL2 to block
- Data comparison > Data to compare:[site:current-page:url] then URL3 to block
- ...

**Actions**:

- Show a message on the site
- Page redirect to home

I want to supply a list of URLs in one field rather than multiple data comparison conditions, is this possible in Rules?

Comment: You need to use PHP Snippet rather than other events. In PHP code use an array, which will have all the blocked URLs and compare `request_uri()` with this array (`array_search()` or `in_array()` will come in handy.

Comment: Are you saying to do this outside of Rules in a module? Sorry, slightly confused.

Comment: No you can execute PHP Snippets as part of Rules module, instead of Events you need to choose Execute as PHP Code in the drop down. Test your rules in local environment once as errors in codes can sometimes break your site.

Comment: @GoodSp33d Using PHP snippets as part of Rules (Conditions or Actions) is something you should try to avoid whenever you can. Have a look at my answer to this question here how you can do so, without PHP.

Answer (score 2):

Assume the relative paths for your 3 URLs are like `my/path1` (for `ULR1`),  `my/path2` (for `ULR2`) and  `my/path3` (for `ULR3`). And assume your homepage has a relative path `MyHomePage`. And assume this question is about D7.

With these assumptions, you could use a rule that answers your question which looks like so (in [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) export format):

```
{ "rules_limit_access_to_some_urls" : {
    "LABEL" : "Limit access to some URLs",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "ON" : { "init" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "data_is" : {
          "data" : [ "site:current-page:path" ],
          "op" : "IN",
          "value" : { "value" : [
              "my\/path1",
              "my\/path2",
              "my\/path3"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "redirect" : { "url" : "MyHomePage" } },
      { "drupal_message" : {
          "message" : "Access to the content located at \u0022\u003Cstrong\u003E[site:current-page:path]\u003C\/strong\u003E\u0022 is not allowed.",
          "type" : "warning"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Note `site:current-page:path` token in this rule, which is different from `site:current-page:url`.

To make the above rule work in similar situations, just adapt the paths by changing 'my/pathX' (with X=1, 2, 3) to whatever fits. And adapt the message to be shown.

Some more samples where you can see this technique at work:

- [How to use the Rules module to implement a custom redirect for an outdated URL?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/170742/how-to-use-the-rules-module-to-implement-a-custom-redirect-for-an-outdated-url/170745#170745)
- [How to hide the content of nodes/ completely, and still maintain use within Drupal 7?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/11427/how-to-hide-the-content-of-nodes-completely-and-still-maintain-use-within-drup/182407#182407)
- [What is the best way to restrict website's direct access through node urls?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/167012/what-is-the-best-way-to-restrict-websites-direct-access-through-node-urls/167032#167032)

**Remark**: Instead of using a data comparison in this Rules Condition, you may also want to try using a text comparison. That would allow you to use regular expressions. If your URLs have a common pattern for which you can write to single regular expression (such as URLx, with x=1, 2, 3, ..., 456, 457, ...), you would only need 1 such Rules Condition.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what are you looking for by using "**Execute custom PHP code**"  as @2-Stroker mentioned.

If you consider **Execute custom PHP code** as an option to solve your issue, you need to do the following:

- First enable **PHP filter module**
- In your rule add a condition element
- In condition dropdown list select **Execute custom PHP code**
- In the PHP code section add the following code and change URLs accordingly

code:

```
$urls = array('/admin/whatever-url-1', '/admin/whatever-url-2', '/admin/whatever-url-3');

if(in_array(request_uri(), $urls)) {
  return true;
}
```