# Best way to deal with node data that should only be displayed in views

Tags: views, entities

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to prevent access to Views-only content?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/5622/how-to-prevent-access-to-views-only-content)

Sometimes I build a content type whose data really only makes sense to display in a View.  An example would be a content type called "Slide" and a View called "Slideshow". I may not want people or search engines to actually go to the node because the slideshow is displaying a series of slides, and by itself, the "Slide" is not very interesting.

So what strategies do site builders usually employee in this situation? Do they style the "Slide" node so that if someone goes there, it looks OK? Do they un-publish the "Slide" so only admins can access it, and then program the view to not filter on only published content?

Comment: If this question is closed as an exact duplicate, it would be nice if the system linked to the previous question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple strategies here...

One is the obvious one you mention: Don't publish the 'Slide' content type, so it never appears on the 'live' site.

Another is that you don't make special 'slideshow' content types. You just add fields to your normal content types that will be displayed in a slideshow display mode. Then you hide them for other display uses like Default and Teaser.

Drupal's flexibility with this type of scenario is one of its major strengths. But it also means that site editors have to remember which field does what, or which type of nodes not to publish.

Comment: What the OP called "Slideshow" is a view, not a content type.