# Remove link from content header

Tags: 6, nodes, navigation

The website I'm building has a lot of content that I do not want linkable to the actual node. Is there a way to remove the link in the content headers?

Comment: There are a few near duplicates of this, though asked in slightly different contexts.  One of which is http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/324/how-do-i-hide-drupal-nodes-that-shouldnt-be-directly-accessed-from-users-and-se

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of different methods for doing this.

The basic idea is to detect the content type using one of a few methods and calling `drupal_not_found()`.  When doing this, I typically set the pathauto for these to `no-view/[nid]`, and then detect the `request_uri` in a hook.  There are some variations, but the all do something really similar.

However, there is a newish module called [Rabbit Hole](http://drupal.org/project/rabbit_hole) that eliminates the need for custom modules and provides a lot of flexability to how you hide the content.  I had been working on a general use module that did something similar, and abandoned developing it when I found this.  From the project page:

> [It] works by providing multiple options to control what should happen when the node is being viewed at its own page. You have the
>   ability to
>
> - Deliver an access denied page.
> - Deliver a page not found page.
> - Issue a page redirect to any Drupal path.
> - Or simply display the content (regular behavior).
>
> This is configurable per content type and per node. There is also a permission that lets certain roles override Rabbit Hole completely.

Comment: I'm implementing Rabbit Hole to return them to the frontpage if anyone attempts to access the node directly, and I ended up creating some PHP directives in node.tpl.php based on the taxonomy of the content. The reason I approched it with this method is to give control to editors/content builders to either link it or not link via the content title just by entering a taxonomy term. I added a couple additional functionality like to be able to remove titles altogether, and even disable publishing information. However, rabbit hole is a fallback in case someone attempts to hack the URL to access it.