# Hide individual node pages

Tags: nodes, users

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I hide Drupal nodes that shouldn’t be directly accessed from users and search engines?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/324/how-do-i-hide-drupal-nodes-that-shouldnt-be-directly-accessed-from-users-and-se)

I was wondering what is the best way to hide a node page?

I am using a content type (book page) to create my books and I have a library page (a view) to list all the books, I dont wan to have any individual book pages visible to the users.

I have tried playing with node access modules and they didn't work for me.

I would still like to the access level to TRUE so I can refer to that node from other nodes/views by reading their content, but I don't want the users to see that particular node page.

How do I do that?

Many thanks

Comment: Make sure you read all of the answers on the question linked above.  Currently, Rabbit Hole is my preferred solution.

Comment: Thank you very much. I haven't seen that post, will read that one instead.